# Can Strapi be configured with a reader & writer database connection?

Tags: strapi

I'm using Strapi with an RDS database cluster backing it. The database cluster has a writer endpoint and a reader endpoint, and the readers can be scaled horizontally, but there can only ever be one writer. Currently, with just very basic Strapi database configuration, 100% of traffic goes through the writer.

I'd like to configure Strapi so that any management through the portal is done using the writer connection, but any querying via API (which an external server does to fetch content) is done via the reader connection. This would be a pretty big benefit for me because those API calls never need to change data, and it would allow me to scale more easily.

I've looked through [the documentation](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/setup-deployment-guides/configurations/required/databases.html) but not seen anything obvious. I've also tried scanning through the code that I already have, but since actually connecting to the database is abstracted so far away from us, I'm not even sure where to start.

Comment: As a note, a possible workaround for this is for me to deploy two different versions of Strapi; one which talks to the writer database endpoint and backs the management portal. And anther which talks to the reader database endpoint, and only handles API queries from the external server.